# How would I loop a certain thing only in Python?

Tags: python, loops

Made this example code:

```
a = input("Insert day: ")
a
if a == "saturday":
    print("Good Saturday!")
elif a == "sunday":
    print("Good Sunday!")
else:
    print("hi")
```

My goal is to "re-do" the whole thing when it's done so ask for input, wait the input, when input is entered then print, then again ask for input and so on..
So I added something to loop it:

```
a = input("Insert day: ")
count = 0
while (count < 1):
    a
    if a == "saturday":
        print("Good Saturday!")
    elif a == "sunday":
        print("Good Sunday!")
    else:
        print("hi")
```

The problem is that this new code loops/spams the print answer, I never really used loop before, as I said i'm trying to get it to ask "Insert day" after it printed the answer and so on, possibly with 1 or 2 seconds delay from print to asking input, how would I do this?

Comment: you can `import time` and add `time.sleep(2)` for it to pause the execution for 2 seconds.

Comment: You can wrap all the code with `while True:` and add a sleep

Comment: A while loop only loops the code indented in it, so without an input or delay of some kind it would just keep on going round as fast as it could...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    count = 0
    while (count < 1):
         a = input("Insert day: ")
         if a == "saturday":
             print("Good Saturday!")
         elif a == "sunday":
             print("Good Sunday!")
         else:
             print("hi")
```

Because you are defining your variable outside the loop, it became infinite.

Answer (score 1):

To ask for user input again, simply place the first line into the loop as well:

```
while True:
    a = input("Insert day: ")
    if a == "saturday":
        print("Good Saturday!")
    elif a == "sunday":
        print("Good Sunday!")
    else:
        print("hi")
```